# Custom route configuration in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, routes

In route file there is a line like

```
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'admins', 'action' => 'login'));
```

I want to do something if anyone write a URL like http://abc.com/webroot or http://abc.com/css_or_js then it also goes to admin's login action. If so then what can i do then?

```
Router::connect('/webroot/*', array('controller' => 'admins', 'action' => 'login'));
Router::connect('/css/*', array('controller' => 'admins', 'action' => 'login'));
Router::connect('/js/*', array('controller' => 'admins', 'action' => 'login'));
```

but it works for `webroot` now and did not work for css or js folder or any other folder. Please help me in this matter. I will be very grateful to you.

Comment: That is pointless. How will you serve actual css files if you are rendering everything as the login page?

Answer (score 0):

The reason the css and js routes aren't working is because Cake's dispatcher is seeing them as an asset, so it [skips the routing process entirely](http://api20.cakephp.org/view_source/dispatcher#l-70) and delivers the asset. The only way around this, as I see, is to write a custom dispatcher.

You shouldn't be writing routes for the webroot directory and its folders anyway. The webroot folder should be the document root on your virtual host, and is therefore seen as the root of the site.